# How to auto-align slight movements in pictures shot for a timelapse?

Tags: image-stabilization, timelapse, auto-alignment

I have been working on a project that I have been documenting for the past few weeks. Unfortunately, the camera mount I built causes slight movements of the camera. Therefore between days there are slightly different positions of the "table" in relation to the picture. Additionally, sometimes there is also a slight shift between pictures (over a few hours the camera tends to slide down very slightly).

I use Sony Vegas Pro for timelapse production... is there a way to put all these pictures into SVP (or any other program), define steady objects and get the program to align all the photos to it? Then I can just trim the empty edges (similar to auto-stabalization)?

Comment: Try Align image stack: http://wiki.panotools.org/Align_image_stack

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I tried using Hugin, however in my output folder I keep on getting a tif and pto files only (2 files instead of 100s of pics). I'll keep on messing around with it and see if I can figure out what I am doing wrong

Comment: @William I think you want to turn on "Remapped images" output. There's more complete instructions for this specific use case here: http://hugin.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/Align_a_stack_of_photos.html

Comment: Hello everyone, I tried the suggestions above. I couldn't figure out the CMD line no matter what I tried. Using Hugin itself was problematic too. I tried loading a series (aprox 500 images). It needed me to enter control points for each single image! At this point I have aprox 2500 images to render and having to do the ctrl points on each one will literally take months Any suggestions or direction to a website that explains the process? I've googled and youtubed all that I can find on using Hugin, yes still no luck!

Answer (score 4):

[align_image_stack](http://wiki.panotools.org/Align_image_stack) is a command-line tool available in the development version of hugin to align overlapping images to facilitate HDR creation, Exposure blending, extended Depth of Field, and Stereoscopic images.

It does exactly what you're looking for, just takes a bunch of images that should overlap perfectly and adjusts them the few pixels/degrees to make that happen, without doing all the complex panorama stuff that Hugin does separately.

Comment: Hello everyone,
I tried the suggestions above. I couldn't figure out the CMD line no matter what I tried.
Using Hugin itself was problematic too. I tried loading a series (aprox 500 images). It needed me to enter control points for each single image! At this point I have aprox 2500 images to render and having to do the ctrl points on each one will literally take months

Any suggestions or direction to a website that explains the process? I've googled and youtubed all that I can find on using Hugin, yes still no luck!

Answer (score 1):

under Linux, this is what I type in a terminal :

align_image_stack -a tif *.JPG

You will a series of aligned TIFF pictures

Comment: Note that this assumes that you have [hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/) installed on your system.